# How Can SSAS cause excel manual filters to reset?

Tags: ssas, excel-2013, ssas-tabular

I have multiple end users linking to a Tabular Analysis Server data cube.

The cube is refreshed (full) every night when the BI `datawarehouse` it draws from is updated. This setup has been in place for over a year.  One morning several users reported that the Excel manual filter for `employeeid` had been reset in all their charts and graphs.

It had been on multi-select, but had been reset to none selected.  Filters for categories, location, etc where unaffected.  Most users where affected, but one was not.  Once the filters are reset, they seem to be staying set again.  The data cube had not been structurally modified for a week before this incident, and the modification was unrelated to the employees data.

I can find no updates for that week to the server or user's machines.

All user machines are Windows7 with Office 2013, the server is Windows 2012 with SQL Server 2014 running in tabular mode.  Since several users at once suffered the effect, I am assuming the server was to blame, but can find no cause.

Anybody with any ideas on this?  They refuse to believe that `Ninja Gremlins` were involved.

Comment: Usually the reason this happens is that the data that was selected in the filter, or the field that was being used in the filter changed in some way.

Comment: Does the employeeID for existing records change in your data warehouse? For example, Type 2 changes.

Comment: They do from time to time, but that has never caused any issues before.